# Nameserver(?) fault but not an obvious one

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have set up my website on a vps, the website is working fine however I am having an unknown issue with nameservers(?).

Basically, I can't crawl the site either with w3 robots or google robots. W3 says it is a nameserver issue and google says that it is a robots.txt issue.

I am 100% sure that it is not a problem with my robots.txt and I have reinstalled the defaults (the site is Drupal) and even tried removing all robots.txt from the server.

Therefore I think it is an issue with nameservers, however all forward and backwards checking nameserver checkers say there is no problem and the website is being server on the domain name without problem.

I think it is a problem with nameservers as I can crawl the ip address correctly with w3.org which returns the content, but the same service will give a '500' error when I type in the domain. Similar issue with google except I can't check the ip.

Could this be an Apache configuration problem?? I really have no idea and can't find any similar issue anywhere.

My site is mercadoingles.com and the ip is 31.200.242.26. I know the obvious answer would be a fault in the robots.txt but you can see the file is correct at mercadoingles.com/robots.txt and I really have no answer as to why the site cannot be crawled properly,

Any bright ideas?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking. What tool are you using and what is the actual error message the tool is returbing. I'm seeing the domain "mercadoingles.com" with authoritative DNS servers "ns.123-reg.co.uk" and "ns2.123-reg.co.uk" returning an "A" record "31.200.242.26" being returned by both DNS servers. I am able to download a "robots.txt" file from the HTTP server at that IP using the hostname "mercadoingles.com" and the IP address above (meaning that Apache isn't returning something different based on a "Host:" header). Everything is looking like I'd expect it to.

Comment: Well, scratch that. Just now the "robots.txt" file is no longer being returned.

Comment: I have reinstalled apache and php to see if that helps thus robots was unavailable - it doesn't help. In answer to your question try to run the site through the validation here http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.mercadoingles.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0, if it was just the validation I could live with it, but google robots also cannot crawl the site due to some unknown error I am trying to identify...

Comment: I can see the robots.txt file fine.  Can you provide the links and URLs for the tools that you are using to test your app ?

Comment: #  Tipo Incidencia Descripción Número de incidencias Ejemplo Líneas Detectado
1
Advertencias
El archivo robots.txt ha bloqueado la URL.
El sitemap incluye URL que el archivo robots.txt ha bloqueado.
40 (extract from google webmaster tools saying is unable to crawl front page)
Valor: http://www.mercadoingles.com/
-
7 ene 2014

Answer (score 1):

Ok - turns out that this was just an a temporary error and was in the caches of google and wc3 as I was configuring the server while changing the NS and DNS settings. One rejected query was cached and several days later this is now working, panic over!